# Removing spaces before command

Tags: babel, tex4ht, french, htlatex

When using French guillemets with TeX4HT, the resulting symbols are not followed/preceded by non-breaking spaces like they should, resulting in wrong line-breaking in HTML.

I tried resetting `\og` and `\fg` with a `babel.4ht` file, but I can't get anything working. The only solution I've found so far is the following:

I defined new `\Og` and `\Fg` commands with:

```
\ifluatex
  \newcommand{\Og}{\og}
  \newcommand{\Fg}{\fg{}}
\else
  \newcommand{\Og}{\HCode{&laquo;&nbsp;}}
  \newcommand{\Fg}{\HCode{&nbsp;&raquo;}}
\fi
```

together with a `sed` hack to remove the spaces before `&nbsp;`:

```
sed -i "s@ *&nbsp; *@\&nbsp;@g" $HTML
```

I'd like to get rid of this and do it properly in a `.4ht` file. How could I do this?

Edit:

The `\Og`/`\Fg` hack is actually acceptable for me, but not the sed one, so I'm modifying the title of this question: How can I remove spaces before the command?

Comment: I don't know TeX4HT (or even HTML for that matter), so I don't know if this comment is relevant, but the stringstrings package can do things like extract substrings, remove leading spaces, etc. You shuld be able to crop strings with it.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. `\removeleadingspaces` from the `stringstrings` package allows to remove leading spaces indeed. However, it doesn't remove the spaces from the string before the `\Fg` call…

Comment: I am trying to understand a concrete example of your need, but am having a hard time, because I am not fluent in your 4ht and html.  I wrote stringstrings, so I have an interest in making it work for your need.  Can you rephrase the problem with a MWE or in a more LaTeX'ey syntax?

Comment: Are there any news here?

Answer (score 5):

You can use just `\unskip` to remove that unwanted space before `&nbsp;`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
some text \og and more text \fg\ and again some text    
\end{document}
```

you can redefine `\og` and `\fg` either in the custom config file or in `frenchb.4ht`:

`hello.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\og{\HCode{&laquo;&nbsp;}}
  \def\fg{\unskip\HCode{&nbsp;&raquo;}}
}
\begin{document}
  \EndPreamble
```

compile with

```
htlatex filename "hello,charset=utf-8" " -cunihtf -utf8"
```

the result:

```xml
<p class="noindent" >some text &laquo;&nbsp;and more text&nbsp;&raquo; and again some text
</p>
```