# unbreakable (thin) space inside « », for tex4ht

Tags: spacing, tex4ht, html

EDIT: @michal.h21

you tip works well, but if I use a numerical code such as `&#8201;` for thin space, instead of its name `&thinsp;` in your modified trick,

```
\def\mythinspace{\HCode{<span style="white-space:nowrap">&thinsp;</span>}}
```

then the `make4ht` outputs an error:

```
(d:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newunicodechar/newunicodechar.sty)
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \mythinspace.
<to be read again>
8
l.29 ...{\HCode{<span style="white-space:nowrap">&#8
                                                  201;</span>}}
?
```

**QUESTION 1** : is it possible to enter a **numerical** name in the definition of `\mythinspace` ?

**QUESTION 2**: is it possible to turn every `~` from my `.tex` used as a thin non breakable space, into a

```
<span style="white-space:nowrap">&thinsp;</span>}
```

in my `.html` ???

For instance, there is also the case of the long dash `---` which must have a non breakable space inside it. I attempt to replace the `tilde` by

```
\catcode`\~=\active%
\def\~{\unskip\mythinspace\ignorespaces}%
```

but of course it no longer shows the `tilde` when I need one: Try to compile the code below with active the replacement of the tilde.

```
    \textemdash~my text in long dash~---\\
    ---~asdmy text in long dash~\textemdash

\~{n}ana un tilde \~{}.

\char`\~
```

you see that the `tilde` disappears. even worse,  the `.html` does not show a replacement of the tilde with the `thin non-breakable space`

```
<!--l. 202--><p class="noindent" ><span 
class="cmr-12">—</span><span 
class="cmr-12"> my text in long dash</span><span 
class="cmr-12"> —</span><br 
class="newline" /><span 
class="cmr-12">—</span><span 
class="cmr-12"> asdmy text in long dash</span><span 
class="cmr-12"> —</span>
</p>
<!--l. 205--><p class="noindent" ><span style="white-space:nowrap">&thinsp;</span><span 
class="cmr-12">nana un tilde</span><span style="white-space:nowrap">&thinsp;</span><span 
class="cmr-12">.</span>
</p>
<!--l. 207--><p class="noindent" ><span 
class="cmr-12">˜</span>
</p>
```

So is it possible to turn every `~` from my `.tex` used as a thin non breakable space, into a

```
<span style="white-space:nowrap">&thinsp;</span>}
```

in my `.html` **while keeping intact the use of `~` when it is used normally, like for accents in `\~{o}`** ???

========= END OF EDIT ============

In my `.tex`, I use both `---` and `\textemdash` and I put always a `~` inside my long dashes.
Nonetheless, in the `.html`, **the `~` are suppressed in being turned into a regular breakable space**.

Is it possible to tell

**I know nothing about `html`**, but I want to output a `.html`, from a `.tex` which is written in `utf8` and contains quotes `«`, `»` and other inputs like this that `lualatex` displays well in a `.pdf`. the problem is that, contrary to `lualatex` which makes unbreakable the spaces inside thequotes, my command

```
make4ht -ul hello.tex
```

does not put unbreakable space inside the `«`, `»`. @michal.h21, [michal.h21, Removing spaces before command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/244862/93524),  gives a solution for replacing, in the `.html`, personal commands in the `.tex` but since **I enter directly the quotes** `«`, `»`, I cannot use them.

For portability in order **to avoid** a `.cfg`, I also want a solution which can be put, in the `.tex`, inside the `\ifx\HCode\undefined \else`:

```
\ifx\HCode\undefined \else
%unusable solution by @michal.h21
%\def\guillemotleft{\HCode{&laquo;&nbsp;}}
%\def\guillemotright{\unskip\HCode{&nbsp;&raquo;}}
\fi
```

A complete document would thus be :

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper, 12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[french]{babel}
%\usepackage[style=french]{csquotes}%
\usepackage{alternative4ht}
\altusepackage{polyglossia}
\altusepackage{fontspec}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\begin{document}

\ifx\HCode\undefined \else
\Css{body{background-color:gainsboro;}}
\Tag{TITLE+}{possibilities for unbreakable space inside « » in HTML}
%unusable solution by @michal.h21
%\def\guillemotleft{\HCode{&laquo;&nbsp;}}
%\def\guillemotright{\unskip\HCode{&nbsp;&raquo;}}
\fi


 ; œ ; Œ ; É ; È ; Ê ; À ; Á ; Å ; Ç

%\euro{}
 ; \oe{} ; \OE{} ; \'{E} ; \`{E} ; \^{E} ; \'{A} ; \`{A} ; \AA{} ; \c{C}

ī \={\i}

My quotes with breakable spaces, once in a html:
« blabla ».

In lualatex, the french spaces for !, ;, : are set properly.
No need for a ~ as in ~!, ~; ~:.





\end{document}
```

[Here, is exposed various spaces in `html`:](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/french.html#spacing)

> The best way to create a fixed-width nonbreaking space in HTML is
>   probably to use the no-break space and style its width. Since the
>   width of an inline element cannot be set in CSS, according to the
>   specifications, we make the element an inline block. This means markup
>   like the following (where   can be replaced by the no-break space
>   character itself:

```
<span class=fine>&nbsp;</span>
```

> The style sheet could be:

```
.fine {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0.125em;
}
```

which gives

```
<div>text before the quote <a class=fine> </a>: «<a class=fine> </a>the quote itself <a class=fine> </a>!<a class=fine> </a>».</div>
```

He says that there is also a `NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE`, along with the ordinary `NO-BREAK SPACE`.

**QUESTION:**

How can I my `«`, `»` in my `.tex` be transformed, in the `html`, into

- `«<a class=fine> </a>`
- `<a class=fine> </a>»`

**in general how can I be sure that the `french spacing` (for `!`, `;`, `:` and so on) is used in my `html` ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better to use a `.cfg` file, which is reusable, than modifying your source file. But you want it, so here it is:

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper, 12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[french]{babel}
%\usepackage[style=french]{csquotes}%
\usepackage{alternative4ht}
\altusepackage{polyglossia}
\altusepackage{fontspec}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\ifx\HCode\undefined \else
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\def\mythinspace{\HCode{<span class="fine"> </span>}}
\newunicodechar{«}{«\mythinspace\ignorespaces}
\newunicodechar{»}{\unskip\mythinspace»}
% \newunicodechar{;}{\mythinspace;}
% \newunicodechar{:}{\mythinspace:}
\fi
\begin{document}
\ifx\HCode\undefined \else
\Css{body{background-color:gainsboro;}}
\Css{.fine{
    display: inline-block;
    width:0.125em;}
}
\Tag{TITLE+}{possibilities for unbreakable space inside « » in HTML}
\catcode`\!=\active%
\catcode`\:=\active%
\catcode`\;=\active%
\def\insertthinspace#1{%
  \def#1{\unskip\mythinspace\detokenize{#1}}%
}
\insertthinspace! \insertthinspace: \insertthinspace;
%unusable solution by @michal.h21
%\def\guillemotleft{\HCode{&laquo;&nbsp;}}
%\def\guillemotright{\unskip\HCode{&nbsp;&raquo;}}
\fi


 ; œ ; Œ ; É ; È ; Ê ; À ; Á ; Å ; Ç

%\euro{}
 ; \oe{} ; \OE{} ; \'{E} ; \`{E} ; \^{E} ; \'{A} ; \`{A} ; \AA{} ; \c{C}

ī \={\i}

My quotes with breakable spaces, once in a html:
« blabla ».

In lualatex, the french spaces for !, ;, : are set properly.
No need for a ~ as in ~!, ~; ~:.
\end{document}
```

we use `\newunicodechar` for  `«` and `»`, for `:`, `!` and `;` we must use catcode to make them active. This way we can declare them as macros and insert any code we want.

We must use `\unskip` for removing previous spaces and `\ignorespaces` for following spaces, we would get two consecutive spaces otherwise.

The result:

[image]